# react set initial state with async/await variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I'm using async/await in Javascript to fetch the user's coordinates based on their ip address. I then use those coordinates as the initial state values of a few React components. The call fetch call works, but it is not being awaited. I guess I have something wrong with my use of async/await. How can I make sure that the fetch call returns before proceding?
Here is my code:

```
let ip_address_coords
const get_ip_coords = () => {
  try {
    let resp = fetch("https://ip-geolocation.whoisxmlapi.com/api/v1?apiKey=<my_api_key>")
    let data = resp.json()
    return {lng: data.location.lng, lat: data.location.lat}
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

(async () => {
  ip_address_coords = await get_ip_coords();
})()

class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super()
    this.state = {
      lng: ip_address_coords['lng'],
      lat: ip_address_coords['lat']
    }
    ...
```

Comment: I don't think that approach makes sense: You should define  `ip_address_coords` as part of a Parent Component state (Application?), then you should add the fetch logic in your Parent Component's componentDidMount method, once the fetch is successful you should set your  `ip_address_coords` state value. Now you have that logic done you could pass `ip_address_coords` as a prop in the child components you want.

Comment: @IrvinSandoval that approach would work and is what I'm currently using, but I'm using these coordinates for a map and that causes the map to double-clutch when it renders, meaning it renders one location briefly, then the next. I'd like to just go directly to the user's location.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem** as my point of view you are using async outer function you have to handle it child function i think.

Use like this because every function have their own context so you have to handle that function individually so you can handle async task it two ways:
**Use async wait on following method**
**Better way of handling use Promiss on inner function then your async wait may work**

```
const get_ip_coords = async () => {
try{
let resp = await fetch("https://ip-geolocation.whoisxmlapi.com/api/v1?apiKey=<my_api_key>")
let data = resp.json()
   return {lng: data.location.lng, lat: data.location.lat}
 } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

OR

```
 const get_ip_coords = () => {
    return new Promiss((resolve,reject)=>{
             fetch("https://ip-geolocation.whoisxmlapi.com/api/v1?apiKey= 
               <my_api_key>").then(res=>{
                    let data = resp.json()
                    resolve({lng: data.location.lng, lat: data.location.lat})
                }).catch(err=>{
                      reject(err)
                })
    })
}
```

You can also use callback mechanism also.

Comment: Thanks but this first one does not fix the problem and in the second one, the promise gets rejected even after fixing the typo on "Promise".

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure why this didn't work as originally written, but the solution I found was to make the componentDidMount method of the component that actually uses the coordinates async.

It looks like this:

```
  get_ip_coords = () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const resp = await fetch("https://ip-geolocation.whoisxmlapi.com/api/v1?apiKey=<my_api_key>")
      const data = await resp.json()
      resolve([data.location.lng, data.location.lat])
    })
  }
  
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      center: await this.get_ip_coords(),
      ...
```